# how to make domain have www using bind

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

Hello I currently was making a private dns server using bind and my lookup works perfectly using host.yoursenecaid.ops but how can I change it to [www.yoursenecaid.ops](http://www.yoursenecaid.ops) , I am kinda new to bind and having issues , I will link all my files at the bottom :)

//var/named/...

```
$TTL    3D //forward look up zone
@       IN      SOA     host.yoursenecaid.ops.      hostmaster.yoursenecaid.ops.(
                2018042901       ; Serial
                8H      ; Refresh
                2H      ; Retry
                1W      ; Expire
                1D      ; Negative Cache TTL
);
@       IN      NS      host.yoursenecaid.ops.
host    IN      A       192.168.XX.1
```

/etc/named.conf

```
options {
        directory "/var/named/";
        allow-query {127.0.0.1; 192.168.XX.0/24;};
        forwarders { 208.67.222.222; }; # This one works at home
        #forwarders { 10.102.100.21; }; # This one works at Seneca
};
zone "localhost" {
        type master;
        file "named.localhost";
};
zone "yoursenecaid.ops" {
        type master;
        file "mydb-for-yoursenecaid-ops";
};
zone "XX.168.192.in-addr.arpa." {
        type master;
        file "mydb-for-192.168.XX";
};
```

//var/named

```
  $TTL    3D
@       IN      SOA     host.yoursenecaid.ops.      hostmaster.yoursenecaid.ops.(
                2018042901       ; Serial
                8H      ; Refresh
                2H      ; Retry
                1W      ; Expire
                1D      ; Negative Cache TTL
);
@       IN      NS      host.yoursenecaid.ops.
1       IN      PTR     host.yoursenecaid.ops.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your first file (I assume it's the file `mydb-for-yoursenecaid-ops`) a record for the hostname `www`. It can either be a CNAME record pointing to `host.yoursenecaid.ops` or another A record, similar to the one you have for `host`, but using the name `www` instead of `host`. So add either

```
www     IN      CNAME   host
```

or

```
www     IN      A       192.168.XX.1
```

You also need to increment your serial in SOA record and reload BIND (usually this is done by `rndc reload`) after you do this change.